# Spawn Quillmane in EQ1

Tags: everquest

How do you get Quillmane to spawn in EQ1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Echelon Forester](http://home.comcast.net/~echelonforester/) has the [spoiler for getting Quillmane to spawn](http://home.comcast.net/~echelonforester/quillmane2.htm). If you have a tracker and aren't dealing with a lot of competition, it should work brilliantly. However, if you don't have a tracker and are dealing with a fair amount of other people killing placeholders, your best bet is to kill everything in the zone and hope for the best. The times I've been able to see or kill Quillmane have been sheer dumb luck.